# Mount VMware Shared Folder to Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: 12.04, mount, vmware, shared-folders

I tried to create a shared folder to my Ubuntu 12.04.3 VM using VMware 5 from my Mac but I don't see the folder anywhere.

I've tried to use some commands as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279535/vmware-shared-folders-not-working-vmware-tools-issue) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135281/shared-folder-settings-do-not-persist-in-ubuntu-12-04-guest-on-vmware-player-win?rq=1), but nothing is still showing... I just get the error:

```
Error: cannot canonicalize mount point: No such file or directory
```

So I make the folder I'm trying to mount to or just try to mount directly to my home folder and get this error now:

```
Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any comments, suggestions or help would be very much appreciated here, I like using the Shared drive feature in VMware...

Comment: Now I'm using VMWare 6, if that makes any difference.